# Exception 'Zend_Locale_Exception' when comparing two dates

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am trying to validate a form, the form accepts two dates and compares them. Below is the function that is meant to validate to validate the two dates.

```
 public function isValid($data) {
        if ($isValid = parent::isValid($data)) {
            $checkin = new Zend_Date($data['checkin'], null, 'en_US');
            $checkout = new Zend_Date($data['checkout'], null, 'en_US');

            if ($checkin->isLater($checkout)) {
                 $this->checkin->addError('Dates are incorrect');
            }

            if ($checkout->isEarlier($checkin)) {
                 $this->checkin->addError('Dates are incorrect');
            }


        }
        return $isValid;
    }
```

When this is run I get the error message

```
500 Application error
exception 'Zend_Locale_Exception' with message 'No date part in 'Select Date' found.'
```

When I die(); the $isValid variable its set to 1 (true) so I know it gets that far.

The $checkin & $checkout variables aren't populated for some reason.

The $data variable does have an array present so i know it pulling some data from the form.
Below is the var_dump(); for the $data variable:

```
array(12) { ["controller"]=> string(7) "booking" ["action"]=> string(6) "search" ["module"]=> string(7) "default" ["checkin"]=> string(11) "Select Date" ["checkout"]=> string(11) "Select Date" ["district"]=> string(1) "0" ["adults"]=> string(1) "1" ["children"]=> string(1) "0" ["quantity"]=> string(1) "1" ["findroom"]=> string(1) "1" ["x"]=> string(3) "151" ["y"]=> string(2) "29" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, the problem was it was tryingto validate a string as a date, I simply added todays date in as default and it works perfectly!